# How to create a loading screen in backbone while calling model fetch?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to setup a loading screen for while a this.model.fetch({}) is occuring, not sure how I can call it... this is my current attempt with an event trigger but it is not triggering...

```
search: function (e) {
      console.log('searching...');
      var eventL = this.vent;
      e.preventDefault();
      var that;

      that = this.model;
      //post instance to the server with the following input fields
      this.model.fetch(
        {data: {
          channel: $('#channel').val(),
          week: $('#week').val(),
          year: $('#year').val(),
          filter: $('#filter').val()
        },
      attack: this.options.vent.trigger('ok', data),
      success: $.proxy(this.storeMusic, this )
    });
    },
```

I want to send the data back too if possible so I can include the values into the search screen.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to save state back to the server, you want the `save` method rather than `fetch`. The `save` method (as well as `fetch`) accept a success callback (see [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save)) which you could use to trigger the event which hides the loading screen.

Something like this:

```
var self = this;

// About to save, fire event to indicate loading screen should be displayed
this.options.vent.trigger('saveStarted');

this.model.save({
  channel: $('#channel').val(),
  week: $('#week').val(),
  year: $('#year').val(),
  filter: $('#filter').val()
},
{
  success: function(model /*, response, options */) {
    // Save completed, fire event to indicate loading screen should be hidden
    // The model is available as the first parameter of the callback
    self.options.vent.trigger('saveCompleted', model);
  }
});
```

Comment: I got it basically I am calling the function that replaces the screen with loading and when the other page is ready to be loaded it changes pages